# Change id div in a loop with two id variables

Tags: javascript, html

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to make a loop in one div, with two div id's ("uno", "otro") to be replaced the same div from time to time

until now i have

```js
setInterval(function() {
  loop = 2;
  total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    total += 1;
    if (total == loop)
      var casa = "uno";


    else
      var casa = "otro";
  }
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = casa;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  console.log(div)
}, 5000);
```

but only print one div,please a little help

Comment: You only create one div?

Comment: yes, only one  @DaveNewton

Comment: To have two divs your loop should contain the div adding code as well.

Comment: @NicolasTenorio So... how will you replace two div IDs if you only have one ID?

Comment: @Avi i need only one div, how change the id

Comment: @DaveNewton i have two id "uno y "otro"

Comment: @NicolasTenorio If you need  only one div,then remove the older div before adding the new one Or change the Id after after selecting the div object.

Comment: @NicolasTenorio Yes, you do have two IDs. But only one div, and the variables you create are local to the function only, and will be reset every time the interval function fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the append/create logic inside the loop:

```
setInterval(function() {
    loop = 2;
    total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        var casa = "";
        total += 1;
        if (total == loop) casa = "uno";
        else casa = "otro";

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = casa;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        console.log(div)
    }

}, 5000);
```

As per your comments, your question is really unclear, for example, is the div present in the DOM at the initial time? I will show you a code that will check if the div was already appended, otherwise it will only change the id:

```
var appended = false, currentId = "";
setInterval(function() {
    loop = 2;
    total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        var casa = "";
        total += 1;
        if (total == loop) casa = "uno";
        else casa = "otro";
    }

    var div = !appended ? document.createElement("div") : document.getElementById(currentId);
    div.id = casa;
    if (!appended) document.body.appendChild(div);
    console.log(div);
    appended = true;
    currentId = casa;
}, 5000);
```

But with this, you will always get the same id, you should check the previous id instead of doing a loop:

```
var appended = false, currentId = "";
setInterval(function() {
    var casa = currentId === "uno" ? "otro" : "uno";

    var div = !appended ? document.createElement("div") : document.getElementById(currentId);
    div.id = casa;
    if (!appended) document.body.appendChild(div);
    console.log(div);
    appended = true;
    currentId = casa;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: you beat me to the solution :)

Comment: I need only one div how replace the id, and the code is making many

Comment: the edit print one div, but i need in the same div, change the id whitout print more div's @taxicala

Comment: well... is the div present in the dom at the start? whats the id? please be more clear in your question... @NicolasTenorio

Comment: Please make sure to be checking my latest edit with the proper appended flag, this code will only append one div the first time and then will only change the id.

Comment: ok sorry, the code create a div (one div) i need to this div change the id time to time whit the two id's ("uno" "otro") but without print new div's only change the id..@taxicala

Comment: @taxicala yes, is that tnks and sorry for my bad english